# Cauchy imply uniform convergence in metric spaces?

Tags: complex-analysis, metric-spaces, uniform-convergence

In *Lang - Complex Analysis - 1999* there is following theorem:

> Theorem.  If a sequence $(f_n)$ of complex functions on $S$ is Cauchy, then it converges uniformly.

Now, since I do no want to the same thing many times (real analysis, complex analysis, metric space) I would like to know what is the best generalization of the theorem above, for instance to a sequence of maps $(f_n:X\to Y)$ between two metric spaces $(X,d)$ any $(Y,d')$.

What are the conditions on $S$ and on the two metric spaces in order for the sequence to converge and to converge uniformly?

> Q: How do I generalize the theorem above to metric spaces?

Comment: What is the metric you put on the space of functions from $X$ to $Y$? What kind of regularity do you assume for your functions?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven the constraints on the metric spaces are part of the question. There is for instance a result claiming that "X compact, Y complete, then C(X,Y) (with a kind of sup metric) is complete (thus Cauchy seq. converge, but not necessarily uniformly); but in the theorem of Lang continuity is not required. My knowledge is too weak to formulate the theorem, but perhaps I can prove it once is formulated.

Comment: You can consider the space of bounded functions from $X$ to $Y$ with the supremum norm. Then this space will be complete iff $Y$ is complete. Is this the kind of statement you are looking for?

Comment: We also need $X\neq \emptyset$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Without compactness of X? Do I then get also **uniform** convergence (point-wise convergence is not enough to get Lang result as a special case)?

Comment: Yes, you get uniform convergence. Compactness is just needed for continuous functions to be bounded (otherwise the supremum norm could be infinite). But in the statement above we restrict ourself to bounded functions by definition, thus we don't need to impose compactness.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thank you. A last point. Lang also uses the sup norm without constraint on S (if I do not miss something) Where does the boundedness comes from?

Comment: It doesn't come for free, we need to assume it. Otherwise the supremum norm will not be a norm.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I agree, I did not mean in our case, but in the case of Lang. But probably the assumption of a sequence to be Cauchy according to the sup norm means that the maps have to be bounded.

Comment: Ok, you get your statement in complete generality, see my answer below. We don't even need a metric on $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a set and $(Y, d')$ be a complete metric space.

Let $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of functions $f_n: X\rightarrow Y$ such that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n,m \geq N$ holds
$$ \sup_{x\in X} d'(f_n(x), f_m(x)) <\varepsilon. $$
Then holds for $x\in X$
$$ d'(f_n(x), f_m(x))\leq 
\sup_{y\in X} d'(f_n(y), f_m(y)) <\varepsilon. $$
Hence, $(f_n(x))_{n\geq 1}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(Y, d')$ and as $(Y, d')$ is complete there exists
$$f(x):= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(x).$$
Now we show that
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sup_{x\in X} d'(f_n(x), f(x)) =0.$$
Pick $N$ such that
$$ \sup_{y\in X} d'(f_n(y), f_m(y)) <\varepsilon/2. $$
Now let $x\in X$. Then there exists $M\geq N$ such that for all $ n\geq M$ holds
$$ d'(f_n(x), f(x))<\varepsilon/2.$$
Thus, we get for $n\geq N$
$$ d'(f_n(x), f(x)) \leq d'(f_n(x), f_M(x)) + d'(f_M(x), f(x)) < \varepsilon/2 + \varepsilon/2 =\varepsilon.$$
As this holds for all $x\in X$ we get for $n\geq N$
$$\sup_{x\in X} d'(f_n(x), f(x)) < \varepsilon.$$
Hence, $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}$ converges unifornly to $f$.